# How to automatically insert `u`(unicode indicator) to `format` function call wherever `format` is used in my python-2.7 code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I want a macro/override kind of solution to convert every instance of

```
"hello {}".format("wörld")
```

to

```
u"hello {}".format("wörld")
```

I can do find/replace for existing code, but I want to make sure that any future call to the `format` function results in the above change.

I have tried

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

and it almost does the job but it converts all string literals to unicode. This results in some old library breaking which requires `str` objects only.

Comment: The `six` module provides a bunch of Python 2/3 compatibility stuff, including [`text_type`](https://six.readthedocs.io/#six.text_type), which is `unicode` in Python 2 and `str` in Python 3. Use as `six.text_type("hello {}").format("wörld")`

Comment: @Kendas People will be writing `"hello {}".format("wörld")` in the future to my code, I just want it automatically converted to be compatible. I can't ask other developers working on my code to write a `u` or `six.text_type`.

Answer (score 0):

At the beggining of your file, just include this statement:

`from __future__ import unicode_literals`

That will make all string literals in the file to be unicode objects by default, just like what happens in Python 3 - 
if you need a Python2 bytes-string, prefix it with `b`.

I know you said you've tried this already, but that is just the way it is:
you should explicitly work with unicode text in your program, and `encode` any text passed to any library calls to the older libraries you mention - and should cover **all** those calls.

Yes - working correctly with text in a multilingual World is tough, and having unicode text everywere was the *major* fix for Python 3. You are facing exactly what lead Python developers to opt into a 10-year-long compatibility break of the language.

I saw that there is a mypy - Python static type-hint checker - that can run in Python 2. Maybe you could tune it to spot all calls to the libraries that require byte-strings in your code, so that there is no risk of you forgetting the encoding part (or declaring of literal with `b""`) prior to calling into those libraries.

Yes, I know the answer won't let you happy. :-)

The one thing I can think of to ease this otherwise would be to have an initial code that would monkeypatch **all** the calls into those "old libraries" you mention with a decorator that would type-check each passed argument and encode it as a bytestring at runtime (and decode all bytestring return values). (And then, yes, use `from __future__ import unicode_literals` and work with unicode-strings only in all your code-base)

As you can see, manually encoding the bytestrings for each call sounds much more sane.